# Badge and privilege notifications are missing

Tags: bug

Seem to have become unreliable.  I've received at least one new privilege and received two badges without notification.

Comment: I've noticed that too, I take it you're the same as me and they appear under the recent achievements button but you don't get the red (?) notification icon that used to indicate something had changed like you still get for comment replies?

Comment: Nope, got no notification at all.  Got the badge for first bounty yesterday, no notification.  Got priv a while ago for approving wiki tag edits, no notification.

Comment: I missed several privilege notifications in my EE.SE career. I think only 'major' ones are  explicitly communicated or so. To the best of my knowledge all badge notifications worked for me, although I rarely really keep track of what badges I should receive.

Answer (score 2):

Badge changes are showing up for me by the bar-graph type **achievements icon turning green** from the default grey (or red, for reputation changes). Presumably there is some list somewhere of what each of the icon colors mean.

Also, "The Script" cycle time seems to have changed. Previously, the Enlightened badge refresh was (apparently) once in two hours, now it seems to be once in 3 or 4 hours. It is likely that other recalculation periods have also changed, hence making the badge and privilege notifications appear unreliable.